# How can I exclude a field from getting Parcelabled?

Tags: android, parcelable

**Before you jump into the *obvious* solution, hear me out.**

I got asked this question in an android interview where I simply said,

*"I would exclude that field from `writeToParcel()` and the `POJO(Parcel in)` constructor"*

To which the interviewer said, *"Well, there is another way too."* which sadly, I didn't know.

So, here goes the question, how can I exclude a field from getting parcelabled other than excluding manually?

Comment: if he was referring to **Parceler library**, then you can ignore field by setting it to private. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Parceler

Comment: You will mark that field with "@Transient" annotation

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758963/how-to-ignore-fields-when-using-parcelize-annotation-in-kotlin.

Answer (score -3):

You add just add @IgnoreOnParcel to the field you want to ignore:

```
   @Parcelize
    data class MyDataClass (val field1: String,
        @IgnoreOnParcel
        val field2: Boolean) : Parcelable
```

Comment: This will not have any effect. '@IgnoredOnParcel' is inapplicable to properties declared in the primary constructor. You also get a Lint warning stating that.

Comment: Thanks for `@IgnoredOnParcel`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758963/how-to-ignore-fields-when-using-parcelize-annotation-in-kotlin.