# How to ignore fields when using @Parcelize annotation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable

I want to ignore a field when using the `@Parcelize` annotation in Kotlin so that the field is not parceled, since this field does not implement the `Parcelable` interface.

Starting with this, we get an error because `PagedList` is not parcelable:

```
@Parcelize
data class LeaderboardState(
    val progressShown: Boolean = true,
    val pagedList: PagedList<QUser>? = null
) : Parcelable
```

Gives:

```
Type is not directly supported by 'Parcelize'. Annotate the parameter type with '@RawValue' if you want it to be serialized using 'writeValue()'
```

Marking as `@Transient` gives the same error as above:

```
@Parcelize
data class LeaderboardState(
    val progressShown: Boolean = true,

    //Same error
    @Transient
    val pagedList: PagedList<QUser>? = null
) : Parcelable
```

There is an undocumented annotation I found called `@IgnoredOnParcel` which gives the same error, and a lint error on the annotation:

```
@Parcelize
data class LeaderboardState(
    val progressShown: Boolean = true,

    //Same error plus lint error on annotation
    @IgnoredOnParcel
    val pagedList: PagedList<QUser>? = null
) : Parcelable
```

The lint error in that case is: 
`@IgnoredOnParcel' is inapplicable to properties declared in the primary constructor`

Is there really no way to do this with @Parcelize?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use a regular class and move the property out of the primary constructor:

```kotlin
@Parcelize
class LeaderboardState(
    val progressShown: Boolean = true,
    pagedList: PagedList<QUser>? = null
) : Parcelable {

    @IgnoredOnParcel
    val pagedList: PagedList<QUser>? = pagedList
}
```

This is apparently the only solution. Make sure to override equals, hashCode, toString, copy, etc as you need them because they won't be defined for a regular class.

EDIT: Here's another solution so you don't lose the features of the data class and you don't lose the automatic parcelization. I'm using a general example here.

```
data class Person(
    val info: PersonInfo
    val items: PagedList<Item>? = null)

@Parcelize
data class PersonInfo(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val age: Int
) : Parcelable
```

You save only `Person.info` and recreate it from that.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem this is the only solution.  Not really ideal as now I have to implement all of those methods I get for free with a data class.  It would be easier to just implement my own parcelable implementation instead, so it seems @Parcelize isn't really useful for a data class in this case

Comment: @PhillyTheThrilly  I added another solution if you're interested.

Comment: thank you, that is a pretty good workaround.  For now I am just moving the PagedList out of the data class constructor and making it a var so I can set it without needing the copy method.  Your solution is cleaner

Comment: your first suggestion doesn't seem to be valid as you're forced to declare each constructor parameter as either val or var

Comment: That's only true for a `data class`, not a normal `class`.

Comment: @Nicolas, is there any related for this question also, https://stackoverflow.com/q/70800105/10991969

Comment: the first solution wont work, it won't compile with this error:
'Parcelable' constructor parameter should be 'val' or 'var'